# What is the meaning behind Not Nineteen Forever by The Courteeners?

Tags: meaning

I was just wondering if anybody knew what the meaning behind this song is? None of the lyrics seem to relate to the name of the song

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The actual meaning of this song comes from the fact that the band are massive Manchester United fans. They came up with the song for when the club reached 20 League titles and surpassed the previous record of 19 which was held by Liverpool.

It was used as their title winning song when they secured their 20th title.

Hope this helped.

Answer (score 2):

Liam Fray, who wrote the song in 2008, explains it in a [video](https://www.radiox.co.uk/artists/the-courteeners/not-nineteen-forever-meaning-lyrics/) for RadioX:

> It’s about, I guess, growing up, not wanting to grow up...

He hints at Britain's binge drinking culture:

> Well, the first lyric is: ‘She tried to peel me off the pavement,’ so if you want to know why it’s connected with the British public I would guess…
>   I don’t know if that’s a great representation of who we are, but maybe. I guess there’s a lot of honesty.
>   It’s quite an honest album. I think It’s overlooked because people think it’s just about going out and getting smashed and forgetting it.

The Manchester United football team who won their 20th League Championship in 2013 adopted the song as a sort of 'theme song'.